# Is research of the Hyers-Ulam stability of this functional equation already conducted?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, functional-equations

The functional equation in question is of the type $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$, where $f$ is the unknown function. Are there existing research already conducted on the Hyers-Ulam stability of this generalized equation?

Thanks in advance!